# I need to Trigger a Jenkins job when a new folder copied completely to a directory

Tags: jenkins

I need to trigger a jenkins job when a build(folder) copied completely to a directory. Here build folder copy will take some time. My requirement was to wait until folder copy complete and jenkins job should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a various way, Take a look at my example

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('copy') {
            steps {
              sh """
                cp -r /path/from/copy /path/to/copy
              """  
            }
            
        }
        stage('other') {
            steps {
                rcho "I will run after copy stage is done"
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    // you can take advantage of post DSL for your scenario as well
    post {
        success {
            echo "I will run when job is success"
        }
        failure {
            echo "I will run when the job is fail"
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Samit,
is there any python solution for this kind of watch folder

Comment: Not only python, but you can also achieve this scenario in almost all the scripting language.  
If you like the above answer, accept it so that others will get benefit from it.